# How to switch database/schemes at login in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to switch the Database/Schemes after login in Spring Boot Web Application

Algorithms.

1. Login in the application.
2. Select Database that I want to use from this point beyond.

Comment: The scheme tag is for the scheme programming language.

Comment: Should the user select the corresponding database or should this happen automatically? If second: How is the database determined? Thinking of using an `AbstractRoutingDataSource` which gets the db connection from a Map or something else. Further you should be aware for that creating a connection has heavy costs. Do you create the connection pool in advance?